# How to Cache with QueryBuilder and Paginator in Phalcon?

Tags: caching, pagination, phalcon

I have a question about Cache in Phalcon. It is connected with Pagination and QueryBuilder. So, i will give u example:

```
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->columns('a.*, m.*')
    ->addFrom('Models\Articles', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('Models\Multimedia', "m.parent_id=a.id AND m.is_default=1 AND m.subtype='pictures' AND m.type={m_type:str}", 'm')
    ->where('a.i18n={i18n:str} AND a.is_active_from IS NOT NULL AND a.is_active_from <= {today:str}', [
        'i18n' => $this->session->i18n, 
        'm_type' => 'Models\Articles',
        'today' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ])
    ->orderBy('a.is_accent DESC, a.date DESC, a.id DESC');

$paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder([
    "builder" => $builder,
    "limit" => 33,
    "page" => $this->request->getQuery('page', 'int')
]);

$this->view->page = $paginator->getPaginate();
```

Now... if we skip the part with query parameters and clauses... so... my question is:

**HOW to add cache to query here?**

In Phalcon documentation i can add *->cache* only with *getQuery* function, but in my case- there is no such thing here.

So, the question remain: how can i use cache in that situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... after a weeks of thinking xD ... i find some good answer for my issue.

First we need to have cache service in Phalcon:

```
$di->set('dataCache', function() use ($config) {
    $lifetime = 60*60; // 1 hour
    if ($config->development) {
        $lifetime = 60; // 1 min
    }

    $frontCache = new \Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Data([
        "lifetime" => $lifetime
    ]);

    $cache = new \Phalcon\Cache\Backend\File($frontCache, [
        "cacheDir" => $config->application->cache_dir."data/"
    ]);

    return $cache;
});
```

Now go in controller, where is my pagination (you can compare from first post):

```
     $builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
        ->columns('a.id, a.slug, a.is_accent, a.type, a.title, m.*')
        ->addFrom('Models\Articles', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('Models\Multimedia', "m.parent_id=a.id AND m.is_default=1 AND m.subtype='pictures' AND m.type={m_type:str}", 'm')
        ->where('a.i18n={i18n:str} AND a.is_active_from IS NOT NULL AND a.is_active_from <= {today:str}', [
            'i18n' => $this->session->i18n, 
            'm_type' => 'Models\Articles',
            'today' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ])
        ->orderBy('a.is_accent DESC, a.date DESC, a.id DESC');

    $paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder([
        "builder" => $builder,
        "limit" => 33,
        "page" => $this->request->getQuery('page', 'int', 1)
    ]);

    // Cache
    $cache_key = 'articles-index-'.$this->request->getQuery('page', 'int', 1);
    if ($this->di->has('dataCache') and $this->dataCache->exists($cache_key)) {
        $this->view->page = $this->dataCache->get($cache_key);
    } else {
        $this->view->page = $paginator->getPaginate();

        if ($this->di->has('dataCache')) {
            $this->dataCache->save($cache_key, $this->view->page);
        }
    }
```

So, the important part is the **last few lines** after "// Cache" comment :) I didnt cache the query, i cache all paginator data. For optimization it is good idea to specify which columns we need (in my situation i have a column content with huge texts, so i didnt need it). One more thing- *do not forget to flush* cache (from model from example) when you change/delete some element... something like this (in Model):

```
public function afterDelete()
{
    // Clear articles cache (but first check if we have that service)
    if ($this->getDI()->has('dataCache')) {
        $this->getDI()->get('dataCache')->flush();
    }
}
```

And that it is. From 127ms request, now ive got 40ms and less :). Good luck all :)

Some useful links: [Phalcon Models Cache](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html), [Improving Performance in Phalcon](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/cache.html), [Phalcon File Cache](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Cache_Backend_File.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since getQuery() calls getPhql() [internally](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/query/builder.zep#L1343) anyways, the simplest solution I see is just call
`->getPhql()` on the query builder, then from there toss the string to createQuery like so:

```
$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql);
```

From there call `$query->cache(...)` followed by `execute()` as [normal](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html#caching-phql-queries).
getPhql() isn't as hacky as it may seem as they propose its usage in the [caching](https://docs.phalconphp.com/uk/latest/reference/models-cache.html#caching-based-on-conditions) section of the manual.

Comment: Can u explain more? I mean can u give me example with Paginator?

Comment: Actually, on second thought, my approach is just a longer way to do  `->getQuery()->cache(...)` because `getQuery() -> <QueryInterface>`returns [`Phalcon\Mvc\Model\QueryInterface`](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/queryinterface.zep) which has a [cache](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/query.zep) method.

Comment: In terms of paginating, though, you could send the cached data to [Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Paginator_Adapter_Model.html). You can also cache the [resultset](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html). Don't have the time now, but will try to add an example tomorrow. The Phalcon forums have a few examples.

Comment: But where i should use getQuery? ... i will wait for example with paginator. However, didnt find nothing in phalcon forum :/